# relationship between quantitative variables and qualitative variables

Tags: regression, machine-learning, correlation

How can we determine the relationship between quantitative variables and qualitative variables?
for example : AGE (20, 45) and GENDER (Male, Female)  ?

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? What do you mean by "relationship"? What kind of data do you have?

Comment: By relationship I mean a number that quantifies a type of correlation and dependence. And I wonder if it's make sense to compute Cramér's V  between these variables